# get the value from hashmap and add in listview

Tags: android, hashmap, android-listview

I have a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

in the map there are some value. I want to get the value one by one and add it in listview. The value which is in map are

> {Intent { cmp=Bluetooth/300 }=300, Intent { cmp=Audio/400 }=400,
>   Intent { cmp=Video/500 }=500, Intent { cmp=Display/100 }=100, Intent {
>   cmp=WiFi/200 }=200}

There are two textview in the listview.
And I want to be display in listview as

> Display 100
>
> WiFi 200
>
> Bluetooth 300.

Now I public my Adapter Class which will be helpful to you...

```
private class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public NewAdapter(IntentTestingActivity intentTestingActivity,
                HashMap<String, Integer> map) {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Map size is: " + map.size());
            return map.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = view;

            if (v == null) {

                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.class_name, null);

            }

            TextView className = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView tagName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tag_name);

            Integer key_name;
            key_name = map.get(name);

            Log.d(TAG, "Complete map is: " + map.toString());

            // String tag = map.get(tagName).toString();
            // Integer name = map.get(className);

            String keyName;
            keyName = map.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "KeyName is: " + map.get(tag));

            for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); ++i)
                Log.d(TAG, "Tag is: " + tag + " and Name is: " + name + " and Intent is: "+intent);

            HashMap<String, Integer> hashmap = map;
            for (Entry<String, Integer> e : hashmap.entrySet()) {
                String key = e.getKey();
                int value = e.getValue();

                Set<String>keyname = map.keySet();

            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key+ " Value: "+value);
            }


            className.setText(name.toString());
//           tagName.setText(keyName);
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Where name is a just String in which holding all keyValue, such as Display, Vedio ect.

Thanx in advance...

Comment: I do not understand all these +1 and favorites? Am I missing something :$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a POJO class with getter-setter and set the key and value to that class.

```
        List<POJO> list = new ArrayList<POJO>();
        Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry< String, Integer> entry;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            POJO obj = new POJO();
            entry = iterator.next();
            Log.d("Key Value",entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
            obj.setKey(entry.getKey());
            obj.setValue(entry.getValue());
            list.add(obj);
        }
```

And then set this `list` to your Adapter class. This is will be an easy way.

Comment: I make allready a custom adapter. and in the getview method I wrote    Integer key_name;
 key_name = map.get(name);

className.setText(name.toString());

where className is the Textview. But in the listView print onle Video. But I want to be print all name.

Comment: in the getview method I wrote? what you wrote? post the code.

Comment: I provide the code which is write in getView method of my customAdapter.

Comment: In `map.get(name);` from where you are getting `name`?

Comment: public void initMap() {
  String[] getPackate;

  getPackate = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Class_Name);
  int len = getPackate.length;

  Log.d(TAG, "Packates len: " + len);

  for (int i = 0; i < getPackate.length; ++i) {
   String[] separated = getPackate[i].split(",");
   if (separated == null)
    continue;
   for (int j = 0; j < separated.length; ++j) {
intent.setClassName(separated[0], separated[1]);
tag = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);
String name = separated[0];

    map.put(intent.toString(), tag);
    Log.d(TAG, "Tag is: " + tag + " Intent is: " + intent);
}  
}
}

Comment: that won't be helpful in reading post code in question itself.

Comment: name is just a String in which I take all name of Key. Such as Display, Vedio, wifi etc. If you want to be source code then please provide me your mail id. I will be mail you.

Comment: you have to post your adapter class this way its not helpful at all.

Comment: Your `for loop` inside the adapter class will be called for every list item so its bad coding standard, better is to do as I insisted and just pass the `list` to the adapter class.

Comment: yea I do it, But it is not helpful. Still it print Vedio only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7311/discussion-between-android-boy-and-lalit-poptani)

Answer (score 0):

Build a custom Adapter that uses your HashMap and...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are showing both values together as a single string, so you may achieve this by simply doing in this way:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.id.text1);
for(String key : map.keySet()){
    adapter.add(key + " " + map.get(key));
}
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I thought to provide answer as he's showing both elements as one string. Otherwise extending to a custom adapter is his best bet

Comment: I already print in the listView by customAdapter. But in the listView show only Vedio. But I want to be print all things which is in map. the code which is write in getview method is already given below comment.

Comment: Integer key_name; key_name = map.get(name); className.setText(name.toString()); where className is the Textview.